# Imitate Quote Style with Tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I imitate the below quote style, say with `tcolorbox`? (The exact diamond shape in the middle is not essential but it is important that I can put something there.)

[image]

Comment: You're member for more than 3 years, with a relatively high reputation, you should know what a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is. Please edit to your question adding what you've tried so far, as is, it's a _just-do-it-for-me_ one.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a `tcolorbox` with a `diamond` shape node at the frame west border, but drawing only one border line.

The content of the diamond is given as second argument, here a `\bccrayon`.

The spacings and positioning of the borderline may be adjust depending on the size of the 'diamond content'.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}


\makeatletter
\NewTColorBox{quotebox}{+O{}+m}{%
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  frame hidden,
  borderline west={\kvtcb@left@rule}{-2pt}{tcbcol@frame,},
  colback = white,
  left=15pt,
  #1,
  overlay={%
    \node[inner sep=0pt,diamond,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule,draw,tcbcol@frame, fill=white, % some more options here eventually]
    ](framenode) at ($(frame.west)+(-2pt+\kvtcb@left@rule/2,0)$) {#2};
    }   
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{quotebox}{\bccrayon}
  \blindtext
\end{quotebox}


\begin{quotebox}[colframe=blue]{\bccrayon}
  \blindtext
\end{quotebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
path p ; numeric w, h, o ;
w := OverlayWidth ; h := OverlayHeight ; o := BodyFontSize ;
draw (0,h) -- (0,0) ;
p := unitsquare scaled o shifted (-o/2,(h-o)/2) ;
fill p rotatedaround (center p, 45) withcolor white ;
draw p rotatedaround (center p, 45) withpen pencircle scaled 2pt ;
setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xyscaled(w,h) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [FunnyFrame]
  [\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]

\defineframedtext
  [FunnyText]
  [align=flushleft,
   frame=off,
   background=FunnyFrame]

\setupbodyfont[antykwa]

\starttext

\startFunnyText
\input lorem
\stopFunnyText

\stoptext
```

[image]